# Maximizing / Optimizing 3 results at the same time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization, max

I have a csv file with more than 100 columns and 3500 rows which looks like this (just an example):

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'Profit': [90, -70, 111, 40, -5, -1],
    'Crit1': [True, True, False, True, False, True],
    'Crit2': [False, False, False, True, True, False],
    'Crit3': [True, True, False, True, True, True],
    'Crit4': [False, True, True, False, False, False],
    'Crit5': [True, False, False, True, True, True]
})
```

I'd like to define 3 results:

1 - totalProfit: is the sum of the column "Profit"

2 - posValues: how many positive values in the column result

3 - negValues: how many negative values in the column result

```
totalProfit = data['Profit'].sum() # The sum is 165
```

In this example, posValues will be 3 and negValues will be 3. But I don't know how to count them with a formula.

I'd like to find the best combination of the columns filtered (true / false) to increase the posValues and decrease the negValues, while maximising the totalProfit.

By guess, I think that the best combination is : Crit1 and Crit5 set to True

```py
print(data[(data.Crit5 == True) & (data.Crit1 == True)])

totalResult = data['Profit'][(data.Crit5 == True)  & (data.Crit1 == True)].sum()

print(totalResult)
```

So, with this combination, we'll have totalResult = 129, posValues = 2 and negValues = 1 and the combination is : Set Crit1 and Crit5 to True

Please keep in mind that, it's not mandatory to filter all the columns, I can have some unfiltered (as in the example).

How can I have a code that will increase the posValues and decrease the negValues, while maximising the totalProfit, and display what combination of True/False columns is the best, please ?

Comment: Please post some sample data and any code that you've already written. Also, can you please clarify what you mean by "Please keep in mind that, it's not mandatory to filter all the columns, I can have some unfiltered."?

Comment: Could you  please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Also, are `posValues` and `negValues` counts or sums?

Comment: Hello, 
@Kapocsi I have edited my question to add a sample data at the end. My knowledge of python is basic, this is why I don't know where to begin.

Thank you

Comment: @PierreD Unfortunately, I don't have a minimal example, I tried to do it in Excel but it has limitations I think, this is why I thought about Python. The posValues and negValues are counts (not sums)

Thank you

Comment: MRE: make a smaller example with just enough columns and positive/negative numbers to exhibit the core of your question. Also, in order to get the best help here on SO, make it as easy as possible for people to copy/paste your example and get started fast. Guessing and reading between the lines of a long question is a bit off-putting.

Comment: @Kapocsi What I mean by: " "Please keep in mind that, it's not mandatory to filter all the columns, I can have some unfiltered." is that some columns can be unfiltered (will have true and false values at the same time). The main goal is the maximization of the totalResult by optimizing the posValues over the negValues.

I really hope it is clear.
Thank you

Comment: @PierreD I have done what you suggested, can you please take a look now ?

Comment: @Kapocsi I have completely edited my question as suggested by Pierre, would you please take a look at it now ?

Comment: thx for the MRE, very helpful; one more thing: how do you mitigate the three objectives: 1. maximize(posCount), 2. minimize(negCount), and 3. maximize(Profit)?

Comment: One important question is how do you compare solutions? Say one solution gives a total profit of 1000, but posCount 90 and negCount 10. Another gives a total profit of 999, but a posCount of 100 and a negCount of 0. Which one wins? (In my solution below, I assume that the desired solution is the last by `order by totalProfit, posCount, negCount desc`.

Comment: @PierreD yes the latter is the right one for me too. Thank you very much. I'll try to see the problem from different angle, maybe cvxpy, if it will suit the situation... I'll try :)

Comment: pls check out my new answer: it provides a less naive algorithm, suitable for 100 columns or more on a single core.

Comment: @PierreD Thank you so much for your time, I will dig what you have sent, will try to understand it and get back you. Many thanks to you  !

Comment: @PierreD I have posted an answer with your entire code, but I have a question please:
How can I see what columns that the algo had set to true or false ?

Comment: you mean what is the best result retained by `beam`? It is `beam.best` (a `candidate`); its column set is `beam.best.k` and its profit is `beam.best.tot`. As an aside: better to ask questions as comment to an answer, so we know the context...

Answer (score 4):

## TL;DR

We present here an efficient algorithm that, while still potentially having a worst-case that is exponential time (although a formal analysis might prove that even the worst-case is much better than that), in practice has `O(n^2)` median time and is practical for hundreds of columns.  As a test, the solution for a random `n=120` (selector columns) x `nrows=3500` `df` was found in **15min31s on a single core**.

Warning: fairly long answer below.

## A better algorithmic solution

While my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65361140/758174) focused on the trivial question of how to use pandas for this problem, it only provided a brute-force algorithm (simple and appropriate for small number of columns).  In this answer, I address the computational complexity and how to cut it down to handle the kind of scale the OP mentioned (more than 100 columns, thousands of rows).

My initial intuition was that the problem may be [NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness). The brute force approach has exponential complexity (it explicitly considers the `O(2^n)` combinations of `n` columns). That clearly is infeasible for even medium-size `n`.  Other classic problems fall into that category, e.g. the [Travelling Salesman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) and the deceptively simple [Subset sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).

There is no obvious way to decide that a partial solution in the search path of all combinations is going to lead to the optimum. In fact, observing the solutions found by brute-force, ordered by descending score, shows that that their arrangement can be quite intricate. Here is a heat map of *all* column combinations for a randomly generated `df` with `n=9` (and 500 rows). The rows have been sorted by the original `df.profit` descending. Columns are all the 512 solutions, ordered from best (left) to worst (right). The content of the heatmap is the resulting effective filter (or-ing all boolean columns selected by that solution), `True` shown as black and `False` as white:

[image: solutions can be intricate]

We can, however, find ways to avoid exploring the full combinations by using an algorithm described in the next section.

## Beam search algorithm

A [Beam search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beam_search) is "*a heuristic algorithm that explores a graph by expanding the most promising node in a limited set.*"

We use this approach to maintain a set of candidates (each a promising column subset) that are worthy of exploration.  While often used as a heuristic to find *reasonably good solutions* (but not necessarily the best), **in our case we only discard paths that can provably not lead to the optimum**. As such, as long as we let the algorithm complete, **we are guaranteed to deliver the best solution**. We also observed that interrupting the search partway still yields excellent solutions, and often the optimum itself.

### Definition of a candidate

A `candidate` is a particular column subset (a selection of columns to use in filtering `df`) and has a score corresponding to the profit it yields. In addition to being a solution on its own, it can also be used as prefix for "descendant" candidates, by merging it with another candidate. For example, a candidate `{a,c}` can be merged with another `{d,z}` to produce a new candidate `{a,c,d,z}`.

For a candidate `x`, we store the following quantities:

- `x.k`: the column set
- `x.p`: indicator of rows where `profit > 0`
- `x.n`: indicator of rows where `profit < 0` (we disregard `profit == 0`)
- `x.tot`: `sum(profit | (x.p + x.n))` (total profit for that candidate)
- `x.totp`: `sum(profit | x.p)` (sum of positive-only profit for that candidate)

### Cutting the exploration path

Some observations lead us to aggressively cut down the exploration path:

1. The maximum profit that a candidate `x` and all its descendants can ever hope to achieve is `x.totp`: when adding columns in the column set, one could perhaps reduce the set of negative rows, but never increase the set of positive ones. So `x.totp` is the upper bound of any profit down the exploration path of this candidate.
2. Each candidate should be uniquely visited: after visiting `{a,b}` by merging `{a}` with `{b}`, we could inadvertently revisit the same candidate by merging `{b}` with `{a}`. Thus, when merging `x` with `y`, we require that all columns in `x.k` are strictly smaller than every column `y.k` (`max(x.k) < min(y.k)`).
3. When considering a merge of two candidates, there is no opportunity for improvement if either set of negative columns in one is a subset of the other: reject if `x.n < y.n or y.n < x.n` (`<` here being the 'is strict subset' set operator).

This leads to the following implementation:

```py
class candidate(namedtuple('Cand', 'tot totp k p n')):
    """
    A candidate solution or partial solution.
    
    k: (colset) set of columns (e.g. {'a', 'b', 'c'})
    tot: sum(profit | (p | n)) (sum of profit for all rows selected by this colset)
    totp: sum(profit | p) (sum of profit for positive-only rows selected by this colset)
    p: bool np.array indicating where profit > 0 for this colset
    n: bool np.array indicating where profit < 0 for this colset
    """
    def name(self):
        cols = ''.join(sorted(self.k))
        return cols

    def __str__(self):
        cols = ''.join(sorted(self.k))
        return f'{cols} ({self.tot:.2f}, max {self.totp:.2f}, '
               f'|p| = {self.p.sum()}, |n| = {self.n.sum()})'

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)

def make_candidate(df, k):
    truth = df[k].values if k else np.ones(df.shape[0], dtype=bool)
    xk = frozenset({k} if k else {})  # frozenset can be used as dict key, if needed
    xp = (truth & (df['profit'] > 0)).values
    xn = (truth & (df['profit'] < 0)).values
    xtotp = df.loc[xp, 'profit'].sum()
    xtot = xtotp + df.loc[xn, 'profit'].sum()
    return candidate(xtot, xtotp, xk, xp, xn)    

def merge(beam, x, y):
    """merge two candidates x, y if deemed viable, else return None"""
    if max(x.k) >= min(y.k):
        return None  # avoid visiting same colset several times
    if (x.totp < y.tot or y.totp < x.tot:
        return None  # z could never best x or y
    zn = x.n * y.n  # intersection
    zp = x.p * y.p
    ztotp = beam.df.loc[zp, 'profit'].sum()
    if ztotp < beam.best.tot or ztotp <= x.tot or ztotp <= y.tot:
        return None  # z could never best the beam's best so far, or x or y
    ztot = ztotp + beam.df.loc[zn, 'profit'].sum()
    z = candidate(ztot, ztotp, x.k.union(y.k), zp, zn)
    return z

class Beam:
    def __init__(self, df, best, singles, sol):
        self.df = df
        self.best = best
        self.singles = singles
        self.sol = sol
        self.loops = 0
    
    @classmethod
    def from_df(cls, df):
        cols = [k for k in df.columns if k != 'profit']
        # make solutions, first: empty set, then single-column ones
        oa = make_candidate(df, None)
        singles = [make_candidate(df, k) for k in cols]
        best = max([oa] + singles, key=lambda x: x.tot)
        singles = [x for x in singles if x.totp > best.tot]
        return cls(df, best, singles, singles.copy())

    def add_candidate(self, z):
        if z is None:
            return False
        self.sol.append(z)
        if z.tot > self.best.tot:
            self.best = z
            self.prune()
        return True

    def prune(self):
        """remove solutions that cannot become better than the current best"""
        self.sol = [x for x in self.sol if x.totp >= self.best.tot]

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Beam: best: {self.best}, |sol| = {len(self.sol)}, ' \
               f'|singles| = {len(self.singles)}, loops = {self.loops}'

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)
    
    def optimize(self, max_iters=None, report_freq=None):
        i = 0
        while self.sol and (max_iters is None or i < max_iters):
            if report_freq is not None and i % report_freq == 0:
                print(f'loop {i:5d}, beam = {self}')
            x = self.sol.pop(0)
            for y in self.singles:
                self.add_candidate(merge(self, x, y))
            i += 1
            self.loops += 1
        if report_freq:
            print(f'done {i:5d}, beam = {self}')
```

For experimentation, we can generate random frames:

```py
def gen_colnames():
    for n in count(1):
        for t in combinations(ascii_lowercase, n):
            yield ''.join(t)

def colnames(n):
    if n > len(ascii_lowercase):
        return [f'c{k}' for k in range(n)]
    else:
        return list(islice(gen_colnames(), n))

def generate_df(ncols, nrows = 500):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'profit': np.random.normal(scale=100, size=nrows)})
    cols = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([False, True], size=(nrows, ncols)), columns=colnames(ncols))
    df = pd.concat([df, cols], axis=1)
    return df
```

And then we can test it:

```py
df = generate_df(15)

%%time
res = brute_force_all(df)
# CPU times: user 40.9 s, sys: 68 ms, total: 41 s

%%time
beam = Beam.from_df(df)
beam.optimize()
# CPU times: user 165 ms, sys: 3 µs, total: 165 ms

# verify that we have the same solution as the brute-force
assert beam.best.k == res.colset.iloc[0]

# summary of the beam result:
beam
# Beam: best: bf (2567.64, max 5930.26, |p| = 68, |n| = 51), |sol| = 0, |singles| = 15, loops = 228
```

### Performance

We do not provide a formal analysis of the time or space complexity of our solution (we'll leave that as an exercise for the reader...), but here are some empirical observations obtained on a series of runs on random frames of various sizes:

[image: log-log plot of times]

This log-log plot shows individual run times (points) and median times (lines) for both the brute-force and the beam search. As expected, the brute force time is exponential. The beam search is considerably faster, and the median times appear to be polynomial with `n` (a straight line on the log-log plot). A reasonably good fit for the median time is obtained with a degree-2 polynom (so, `O(n^2)`):

[image: polyfit degree-2]

Note that, up to size `n=64`, in thousands of runs we have never hit the maximum budget we had set `max_iters = 100_000`. The solutions were therefore all optimal.

Note also that there is a long-tail dispersion of the actual time, depending on the complexity of the search surface. Here is the individual times histogram for `n = 64`:

[image: histogram n=64 beam times]

But this is mitigated by the ability to stop the search early. In fact, our observations are that, even in the longest cases, very good solutions (or often the optimal itself) appear quite early in the search.

Comment: This answer is just not informative, but it also provides an excellent solution and a very smart approach to the problem. Thank you for this!

Comment: @PierreD I took a look at the links you provided, it's very interesting and as Vichtor said, it's very smart way. I tried to implement this but I have an error : name 'brute_force_all' is not defined. Can you advise me please ? Thank you

Comment: Did you include the function in his first answer :"Brute force (original) answer"? @NTAlgo

Comment: @Vichtor You are right, thank you. I'll explore the results and get back to you both with what I did.

Comment: Likewise! @NTAlgo Pierre, do you have any ideas why i get the ValueError "max() arg is an empty sequence"  when trying your example above? I get the error when running beam.optimize()

Comment: @Vichtor I was able to run the entire code. I'll post an answer with all the blocks.

Comment: Im sorry for bothering you @Pierre D but is there a simple way to implement so that the function returns the Nth best solutions?

Comment: @Vichtor: about "max() arg is an empty sequence": how did you initialize the `beam` (on what input)? The only use of `max()` by `optimize()` is in `merge()`, and its argument (`x.k`) should never be empty.

Comment: @Vichtor: you mean the top-k best solutions? Possible, but would need a few mods: instead of storing the single best solution, the `beam` should retain an ordered list `top_k` best ones. When rejecting a candidate, compare against the worst of them (`topk[-1]`), instead of `best`. In this sense, the current `best` is a special case of `top_k` where `k==1`. Also, I'm a bit casual in handling "equal" candidates -- rejecting them if they cannot be better than the `best`. This would have to be changed.

Comment: Yes, i meant top-k best solutions, sorry. I will try to implement the mods that you mention above and then post the results here in case you or anyone will have use of it. Also, thank you for the help and the solution that Will save me a lot of time!

Comment: @PierreD When I try to see the retained columns beam.best.k, I have an empty frozenset. I did a '''for xy in beam.best.k:
    print (xy) ''' but nothing is displayed. Is it normal ? Thanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you using the same df as in your example? In that case, the best solution would be None of the criterias

Comment: @Vichtor: yes, but I changed the target column name to `'profit'` (lowercase). This is hardcoded in various places and of course would need to be refactored cleanly in production code. There are various things to do and gain some additional (minor) speedup. I was trying to keep the answer from being even longer than it is.

Comment: @Vichtor Yes, I thought I can figure it out with my example, but it's ok now because I used Pierre's code to generate a new df. I'll apply it to the real dataframe and see how it will go. I'll keep you both posted. Thanks

Comment: folks, I implemented a top k version, plus did a couple of light touches here and there; it seems even faster now (same big-O, but the constants are smaller): it appears so far that, even with `topk=5` the `time ~ 0.00035 n^2` (compared to the previous `0.007 n^2` for `topk=1` single best). More details to follow but I'll let some tests run for a while.

Comment: @PierreD Is it easy to change the code to maximize the number (count) of positive values and minimize the negative ones (no need to take in consideration the total profit), please ? Thank you

Comment: I have tried to change / play with your code, but in vain. Would you please advise me ? What code must I change to maximize the number (count) of positive values and minimize the negative ones (no need to take in consideration the total profit) ? I know it's different from my initial question, but when I applied the code you have shown us, I realized that I have to check this way too. Thank you so much.

Comment: @NTAlgo: as mentioned earlier in comments on your question, "maximize the count of positive values and minimize the negative ones" is not well defined. Do you mean to `order by poscount asc, negcount desc`? In that case it is a very simple search: take whatever column has the largest poscount (`True` where the objective is positive): it is impossible to increase that count by any intersection with another column. If two or more columns are tied by poscount, then break the tie with negative count. To repeat: it is very important to be _precise_ in expressing your optimization objective.

Comment: @PierreD It's not about ordering. Please here is an example: A solution that give 45 poscount, 10 negcount and a totalProfit of 3200 is better than 30 poscount, 40 negcount and a totalProfit 5000. You see, even if the totalProfit of the second solution is greater than the first, but the count (how many) of the poscount is less than the negcount. So, the first solution is the winner. Maybe in other words, I would like the maximize the difference between the poscount (how many positive values) and negcount. Thank you so much

Comment: That's awesome @PierreD! Looking forward to it!

Comment: @NTAlgo: you cannot maximize multiple quantities at the same time. You can either maximize one and break ties with the others, or maximize a weighted combination of them (or any scalar function). That's what we've been telling you (multiple times) since day 1: you **must define** a clear objective quantity to optimize.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did the tests work out? :) @PierreD

Comment: @Vichtor yes, sorry, I never found the time to amend the answer with the changes, but it works great. Now sure wether to edit this answer here or to post a new answer to your (similar) question, as this one here is less relevant to that line of investigation.

Comment: Great! I really liked your solution, I tried to build my own algorithm trying to achieve the same outcome. I can post the results later to share my approach!

Answer (score 2):

This is only a partial answer and doesn't address your optimization question, so please don't accept it at this time.

To calculate how many positive and negative values are in the 'Profit' column you can use the following code:

```py
posValues = (data['Profit'] > 0).sum()
zeroValues = (data['Profit'] == 0).sum()
negValues = (data['Profit'] < 0).sum()
```

Or you can define a function to compute this information:

```py
def sign_counts(values):
    positive = (values > 0).sum()
    zero = (values == 0).sum()
    negative = (values < 0).sum()
    return negative, zero, positive

negative, zero, positive = sign_counts(data['Profit'])



def nonpositive_positive_counts(values):
    positive = (values > 0).sum()
    nonpositive = values.size - positive
    return nonpositive, positive

nonpositive, positive = nonpositive_positive_counts(data['Profit'])
```

Answer (score 2):

## Brute force (original) answer

This answer focuses on the mundane question of *how to use pandas* (and numpy) to find solutions to the problem. It is naive from an algorithmic complexity perspective, and indeed is `O(2^n)` as it evaluates all possible combinations of columns. As such, it is [Exponential time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Exponential_time).

See [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65394551/758174) for a Beam search solution that has median time `O(n^2)`.

In this naive approach, we will:

1. express all combinations of columns (not including `Profit`);
2. define a `filtered` function that filters the data frame based on a given column set;
3. define a `metrics` function that returns a tuple `(sum(Profit), posCount, -negCount)`;
4. compute the metrics for all combinations, and assemble into a `df`;
5. sort the `df` by the metrics tuples.

```py
from itertools import combinations

def metrics(s):
    # returns three quantities on a Series s: sum, poscount, -negcount
    return s.sum(), (s > 0).sum(), -(s < 0).sum()

def filtered(df, combo):
    # given a combo: set of columns, filter the df to keep
    # the rows where all the columns are True
    mask = np.all(df[combo], axis=1)
    return df.loc[mask]

def brute_force_all(df):
    """
    Return all brute-force solutions. O(2^n).
    """
    # get all columns (except for 'profit') combinations
    crit_cols = [k for k in df.columns if k != 'profit']
    combos = [set(combo) for n in range(0, len(crit_cols) + 1)
              for combo in combinations(crit_cols, n)]

    # assemble a df made of metrics and colset
    res = pd.DataFrame([
        metrics(filtered(df, combo)['profit']) + (combo,)
        for combo in combos
    ], columns='total poscount negcount colset'.split())

    # finally, sort to expose the "best" result first
    res = res.sort_values(['total', 'poscount', 'negcount'], ascending=False)
    res = res.reset_index(drop=True)
    return res
```

Example on your data:

```
    total  poscount  negcount                               colset
0     165         3        -3                                   {}
9     129         2        -1                       {Crit5, Crit1}
20    129         2        -1                {Crit5, Crit1, Crit3}
5     124         2        -2                              {Crit5}
14    124         2        -2                       {Crit5, Crit3}
  ...
29      0         0         0         {Crit5, Crit2, Crit4, Crit3}
30      0         0         0  {Crit2, Crit4, Crit5, Crit1, Crit3}
7     -70         0        -1                       {Crit1, Crit4}
12    -70         0        -1                       {Crit3, Crit4}
18    -70         0        -1                {Crit3, Crit1, Crit4}
```

Details:

In order to understand the code above, it is a good idea to inspect some of the quantities we set out to compute. For example:

```py
>>> combos
[set(),
 {'Crit1'},
 ...
 {'Crit5'},
 {'Crit1', 'Crit2'},
 ...
 {'Crit4', 'Crit5'},
 {'Crit1', 'Crit2', 'Crit3'},
 ...
 {'Crit3', 'Crit4', 'Crit5'},
 {'Crit1', 'Crit2', 'Crit3', 'Crit4'},
 ...
 {'Crit2', 'Crit3', 'Crit4', 'Crit5'},
 {'Crit1', 'Crit2', 'Crit3', 'Crit4', 'Crit5'}]

# metrics on the unfiltered (whole) data:
>>> metrics(data['Profit'])
(165, 3, -3)

# data filtered where Crit2 and Crit3 are True:
>>> filtered(data, {'Crit2', 'Crit3'})
   Profit  Crit1  Crit2  Crit3  Crit4  Crit5
3      40   True   True   True  False   True
4      -5  False   True   True  False   True

# metrics on the above:
>>> metrics(filtered(data, {'Crit2', 'Crit3'})['Profit'])
(35, 1, -1)
```

Comment: Your solution evaluates combinations where each column is either True or unfiltered and does not include the case where all columns are unfiltered. — The algorithm checks all 2^5 = 32 combinations. When 100+ columns are included it would try to evaluate all 2^100 or 1.3 nonillion (1,267,650,600,228,229,401,496,703,205,376) combinations. In general, the algorithm you proposed is O(s^c) where s is the number of states that each column can be in (True, unfiltered) and c is the number of columns (100).

Comment: However, the problem is even worse. The OP actually suggested that they want to evaluate combinations where each column is either True or False or unfiltered. This results in ~5 x 10^47 (515,377,520,732,011,331,036,461,129,765,621,272,702,107,522,001) different combinations. If you had access to a [supercomputer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summit_(supercomputer)) that could evaluate 200 quadrillion combinations per second, it would take you approximately 5.9 trillion x the age of the universe to finish your calculation.

Comment: So, needless to say, my math is either wrong, or @NTAlgo will need a different approach. :)

Comment: @Kapocsi: I agree, this is a complete brute-force version. I was just trying to answer the OP's question, not generalize to a large-scale setting. There might be simple heuristics to help speed up the search, but I suspect this is actually NP-hard (a la Traveling Salesman). There are of course good heuristics to find good solutions for those. In this case, perhaps some random projections (e.g. [Ping Li et al](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/Ping/KDD06_rp.pdf)) would be a way to go. Anyway, this seems to be beyond the scope of the question, which unless I'm mistaken was about _how to_).

Comment: Actually, I stand corrected: re-reading the question I see the mention of 100 columns and 3500 rows. So it is also an algorithmic question, not just a _how-to_ one. Good point @Kapocsi.

Comment: @PierreD Thank you for your reply but when I run the code, it shows me 30 combinations having the same total 165 and poscount of 3 and negcount of -3. I don't know why I don't have the same results you had.
Speaking of the approach, if it's not the right one, please advise me something else that will solve the problem. I don't mind the technique as long as I have the totalResult maximised and the posValues greater than the negValues. Thank you

Comment: @Kapocsi Thank you for the functions and if you have different approach, please don't hesitate. Thanks

Comment: @NTAlgo: that's weird; it runs just fine for me. Are you able to run the lines in "Details"?  E.g., what does `filtered(data, {'Crit2', 'Crit3'})` give you?

Comment: re. different approaches: yes, I have a few ideas but no time to investigate now. You may want to ask on https://math.stackexchange.com/ or ask a new question here with an emphasis on the algorithmic approach and how to avoid a combinatorial search.

Comment: @Kapocsi: did a 1-char fix (`range(1, ...)` -> `range(0, ...)`) to also include the solution with the full data (no filtering columns). In the OP's example, it happens to be the winning solution.

Comment: @PierreD I tried it several times and the results are the same. Here is an example: https://imgur.com/ccYgHZv 
I copied the code of the dataframe and append your code and run it. 
Did I miss something ?

And thank you for the advice, I'll try to ask in the other site too.

Comment: Ok, something is wrong about your dataframe then. Are those `Crit...` columns really boolean (they should be). E.g. does `data.dtypes` show `bool` for all columns except `Profit`? I suspect you may have strings in there instead... That would cause this, as `np.all()` would return `True` is they are non-empty strings.

Comment: @NTAlgo Please refer to comments Pierre and I posted above. It is [worth doing some reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness) to discover why you should consider your objective more carefully. Also, don't put quotes around the boolean values, e.g. `'Crit2': [False, False, False, True, True, False],`  and not `'Crit2': ['False', 'False', 'False', 'True', 'True', 'False'],`.

Comment: You both are right about booleans, I deleted the single quotes and they are recognised as bool and I can see the results that Pierre had shown. Thank you both. I'll try to dig it more as you said before, if I want to consider all the combinations, maybe I have to find some other method to do that. I read a bit about cvxpy but this is completely obscure to me, but I'll try. At the same time, if you have any other ideas they are more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Based on all the code of @PierreD:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from collections import namedtuple
from itertools import combinations
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'profit': [90, -70, 111, 40, -5, -1],
    'Crit1': [True, True, False, True, False, True],
    'Crit2': [False, False, False, True, True, False],
    'Crit3': [True, True, False, True, True, True],
    'Crit4': [False, True, True, False, False, False],
    'Crit5': [True, False, False, True, True, True]
})
```

```
def metrics(s):
    # returns three quantities on a Series s: sum, poscount, -negcount
    return s.sum(), (s > 0).sum(), -(s < 0).sum()

def filtered(df, combo):
    # given a combo: set of columns, filter the df to keep
    # the rows where all the columns are True
    mask = np.all(df[combo], axis=1)
    return df.loc[mask]

def brute_force_all(df):
    """
    Return all brute-force solutions. O(2^n).
    """
    # get all columns (except for 'profit') combinations
    crit_cols = [k for k in df.columns if k != 'profit']
    combos = [set(combo) for n in range(0, len(crit_cols) + 1)
              for combo in combinations(crit_cols, n)]

    # assemble a df made of metrics and colset
    res = pd.DataFrame([
        metrics(filtered(df, combo)['profit']) + (combo,)
        for combo in combos
    ], columns='total poscount negcount colset'.split())

    # finally, sort to expose the "best" result first
    res = res.sort_values(['total', 'poscount', 'negcount'], ascending=False)
    res = res.reset_index(drop=True)
    return res
```

```
class candidate(namedtuple('Cand', 'tot totp k p n')):
    """
    A candidate solution or partial solution.
    
    k: (colset) set of columns (e.g. {'a', 'b', 'c'})
    tot: sum(profit | (p | n)) (sum of profit for all rows selected by this colset)
    totp: sum(profit | p) (sum of profit for positive-only rows selected by this colset)
    p: bool np.array indicating where profit > 0 for this colset
    n: bool np.array indicating where profit < 0 for this colset
    """
    def name(self):
        cols = ''.join(sorted(self.k))
        return cols

    def __str__(self):
        cols = ''.join(sorted(self.k))
        return f'{cols} ({self.tot:.2f}, max {self.totp:.2f}, 'f'|p| = {self.p.sum()}, |n| = {self.n.sum()})'

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)

def make_candidate(df, k):
    truth = df[k].values if k else np.ones(df.shape[0], dtype=bool)
    xk = frozenset({k} if k else {})  # frozenset can be used as dict key, if needed
    xp = (truth & (df['profit'] > 0)).values
    xn = (truth & (df['profit'] < 0)).values
    xtotp = df.loc[xp, 'profit'].sum()
    xtot = xtotp + df.loc[xn, 'profit'].sum()
    return candidate(xtot, xtotp, xk, xp, xn)    

def merge(beam, x, y):
    """merge two candidates x, y if deemed viable, else return None"""
    if max(x.k) >= min(y.k):
        return None  # avoid visiting same colset several times
    if (x.totp < y.tot or y.totp < x.tot):
        return None  # z could never best x or y
    zn = x.n * y.n  # intersection
    zp = x.p * y.p
    ztotp = beam.df.loc[zp, 'profit'].sum()
    if ztotp < beam.best.tot or ztotp <= x.tot or ztotp <= y.tot:
        return None  # z could never best the beam's best so far, or x or y
    ztot = ztotp + beam.df.loc[zn, 'profit'].sum()
    z = candidate(ztot, ztotp, x.k.union(y.k), zp, zn)
    return z

class Beam:
    def __init__(self, df, best, singles, sol):
        self.df = df
        self.best = best
        self.singles = singles
        self.sol = sol
        self.loops = 0
    
    @classmethod
    def from_df(cls, df):
        cols = [k for k in df.columns if k != 'profit']
        # make solutions, first: empty set, then single-column ones
        oa = make_candidate(df, None)
        singles = [make_candidate(df, k) for k in cols]
        best = max([oa] + singles, key=lambda x: x.tot)
        singles = [x for x in singles if x.totp > best.tot]
        return cls(df, best, singles, singles.copy())

    def add_candidate(self, z):
        if z is None:
            return False
        self.sol.append(z)
        if z.tot > self.best.tot:
            self.best = z
            self.prune()
        return True

    def prune(self):
        """remove solutions that cannot become better than the current best"""
        self.sol = [x for x in self.sol if x.totp >= self.best.tot]

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Beam: best: {self.best}, |sol| = {len(self.sol)}, ' \
               f'|singles| = {len(self.singles)}, loops = {self.loops}'

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)
    
    def optimize(self, max_iters=None, report_freq=None):
        i = 0
        while self.sol and (max_iters is None or i < max_iters):
            if report_freq is not None and i % report_freq == 0:
                print(f'loop {i:5d}, beam = {self}')
            x = self.sol.pop(0)
            for y in self.singles:
                self.add_candidate(merge(self, x, y))
            i += 1
            self.loops += 1
        if report_freq:
            print(f'done {i:5d}, beam = {self}')
```

```
%%time
res = brute_force_all(df)

%%time
beam = Beam.from_df(df)
beam.optimize()

# verify that we have the same solution as the brute-force
assert beam.best.k == res.colset.iloc[0]

# summary of the beam result:
beam
```

With this code, I have :
Beam: best:  (165.00, max 241.00, |p| = 3, |n| = 3), |sol| = 0, |singles| = 0, loops = 0

Comment: Thank you! I’ll try it out and get back to you Both with my results!